# Proving that if E is countably infinite, and $F \subset E$ is finite, then E\F is countably infinite

Tags: real-analysis

I'm really confused as to how I should prove this. I know that the unions of two countable sets are countable, and that a corollary of this is that finite sets can be countable. I also know this is a two-step proof where I should first prove that $ E \backslash F$ is infinite, and then prove it's countable.

Any guidance or hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Well $E \setminus F \subset E$ so it is at most countable, and if $E \setminus F $ is finite then $E = (E \setminus F) \cup F$ is the union of finite sets, hence finite.

Comment: For added clarity you might wish to point out that you are doing a proof by contradiction here.

Comment: Wow. This is was really simple. Thank you!